# Regex, How to find a repeating group of random numbers?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm currently parsing data from PDFs and I'd like to get the name and amount in a simple format: [NAME] [AMOUNT]

```
 NAME LAST
7 494 25 7 494 25 199 44
 NAME LAST
4 488 00 4 488 00 109 07
 NAME MIDDLE LAST
7 854 00 7 854 00 298 25
 NAME LAST
494 23 494 23 12 01
 NAME MIDDLE LAST
4 301 56 4 301 56 112 61
 NAME M LAST
13 359 25 13 359 25 130 54
```

This data means the following:
[NAME] [M?] [LAST]
[TOTAL WAGES] [PIT WAGES] [PIT WITHHELD]
`NAME LAST $7,494.25 $7,494.25 $199.44`
`NAME LAST $4,488.00 $4,488.00 $109.07`
`NAME MIDDLE LAST $7,854.00 $7,854.00 $298.25`
`NAME LAST $494.23 $494.23 $12.01`
`NAME MIDDLE LAST $4,301.56 $4,301.56 $112.61`
`NAME M LAST $13,359.25 $13,359.25 $130.54`

I'd like a regex to detect the duplicate group of numbers so that it parses to this:
`NAME LAST $7,494.25`
`NAME LAST $4,488.00`
`NAME MIDDLE LAST $7,854.00`
`NAME LAST $494.23`
`NAME MIDDLE LAST $4,301.56`
`NAME M LAST $13,359.25`

Hopefully, that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that no-one in your organisation is making more than $1M or less than $1, this regex will do what you want:

```
 *([a-z][a-z ]+)\R+((\d+)(?: (\d+))? (\d+)) (?=\2).*
```

It looks for

- some number of spaces
- names (simplistically) with `[a-z][a-z ]+` (captured in group 1)
- newline characters (`\R+`)
- 2 or 3 sets of digits separated by spaces `((\d+)(?: (\d+))? (\d+))` (captured overall in group 2, with individual groups of digits captured in groups 3, 4 and 5)
- a space, followed by an assertion that group 2 is repeated  `(?=\2)`
- characters to match the rest of the string to end of line (may not be required, dependent on your application) (`.*`)

You can replace that with

```
$1 \$$3$4.$5
```

to get the following output for your sample data:

```
NAME LAST $7494.25
NAME LAST $4488.00
NAME MIDDLE LAST $7854.00
NAME LAST $494.23
NAME MIDDLE LAST $4301.56
NAME M LAST $13359.25
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sfV5hI/1)

If you're using JavaScript, you need a couple of minor changes. In the regex, replace `\R` with `[\r\n]` as JavaScript doesn't recognise `\R`. In the substitution, replace `\$` with `$$`.

[Demo on regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/5b1lAi/1)

If your regex flavour supports conditional replacements, you can add a `,` between the thousands and hundreds by checking if group 4 was part of the match:

```
$1 \$$3${4:+,}$4.$5
```

In this case the output is:

```
NAME LAST $7,494.25
NAME LAST $4,488.00
NAME MIDDLE LAST $7,854.00
NAME LAST $494.23
NAME MIDDLE LAST $4,301.56
NAME M LAST $13,359.25
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sfV5hI/2)

Comment: That's great, could you do it in Javascript Regex, it appears the PHP Regex is slightly different and I can't make it work!

Comment: @Outcast sorry, you didn't specify your language. Please see my edit for the changes required for JavaScript. Note unfortunately JS doesn't support conditional replacements, you'd have to do that with a callback.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware regex had multiple syntaxes! :)

Comment: @Outcast almost as many flavours as languages :) you'll see regex101 supports 7 different ones...

Comment: I've updated the data in the Demo on regex101, In Some lines, the amounts don't match and only the first one should be taken into consideration  https://regex101.com/r/5IBwVi/1 this data is basically raw from the PDF which has the social before the name and the social can either be 123-12-1234 or xxx-xx-1234 it really depends on the file.

Comment: @Outcast the ones that didn't match don't have the repeated number e.g. `5 035 00 4 882 35 80 05`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245771/discussion-between-outcast-and-nick).